# Max Ternary operator IF statement compare

Tags: php

I have two variable and want to get the maximum value

```
$a=34;  
$b=45;
```

Now I want to get maximum value of them and I can achieve them following way
Method-1:

```
 $max=$a;
    if($a<$b)
    {
        $max=$b;
    }
```

Method-2:

```
if($a>$b)
    {
        $max=$a;
    }
    else
    {
        $max=$b;
    }
```

Method-3:

```
$max=$a>$b?$a:$b;
```

Method-4:

```
 $max=max($a,$b);
```

Now I want to know which one better to use and why.

Comment: Seems like a no-brainer to me.... the built-in `max()` function is there for a purpose, and semantically there's never likely to be any misunderstanding as to what it's doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 4 is arguably the best way.

- The first is overkill.
- The second even more.
- The third is short and concise, but ternary operators don't always add to readability.
- The fourth is a designated method used in the right way.

Another reason to go for `max` is that it supports an 'infinite' number of arguments. You don't want to re-write all your logic if you have to find the max out of 3 values instead of 2.

Comment: I also like max because it supports more arguments,But wanted to know what if it is only 2 variables.and it seems everyone telling me to use max function.Is not ternary faster than max function for 2 variables?

Comment: You would have to measure, but I assume that `max` function would do just that (or something similar). In any case; performance will never be an issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

None of them is better or worse. You can use any of them. Some might be a bit quicker than the other, but in fact you shouldn't care about micro optimization if you don't repeat those operations thousands/million of times

Answer (score 0):

Method 4 - Its purpose is most clear.

If you can do something with a built in function there is no reason at all to make your own (which is what method 1-3 do really)

Answer (score 0):

I think best Method is 4  `$max=max(`$a,$b);`and Method 2 also perfect if you coding advace it's not **overkill** -_-

Good Luck